# Silverlight : Keyboard Support In Full Screen Mode

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, keyboard, fullscreen

When you make your application full screen with below code then the keyboard support is disabling. How can i get rid of that? I want to use keyboard in full screen mode. Is it possible?

```
Application.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen = true
```

UPDATE :

This is only happening with above code. When you use browser's F11 hot key for full screen, the keyboard is enabled. So, how can i find a way for pressing F11 key programmatically? Javascript methods don't work for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a security feature....

you can see more details here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189023(VS.95).aspx

When a Silverlight-based application is in full-screen mode, most keyboard events are disabled. This limitation of keyboard input during full-screen mode is a security feature, and is intended to minimize the possibility of unintended information being entered by a user. In full-screen mode, the only input allowed is through the following keys:

UP ARROW
DOWN ARROW
LEFT ARROW
RIGHT ARROW
SPACEBAR
TAB
PAGE UP
PAGE DOWN
HOME
END
ENTER